# Batch file to check file with the same extension

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So im not so good with code.
I have a code that check the size of a file with the extension `.txt` and i need it to verify all the file with that extention and, if is bigger than the "limit", write a (for example) `size.txt` that inside is the name of the files that exceed the size limit.
The code that i already have, and was given to me is: (it dont have the part of write the file `size.txt`)

```
@echo off

set file="C:\PSTCheck\*.ost"

set maxbytesize=3000

%1 %0 :: %file%
set len=%~z2


if %len% LSS %maxbytesize% (
exit

) ELSE (
msg * O ficheiro exedeu, diriga-se a Informatica

)

exit
```

If it isnt a way to do it please let me know another way of making the code.
It needs to run in different windows version

Comment: `%1 %0 :: %file%` is this mean that you are passing a command or program to the script that should be executed? The `%1` is the first argument passed to the file...

Comment: Questions [very similar to this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+ost&tab=relevance) have been asked before.

Comment: Second time in a matter if days I have seen this exact code. So I will say the same thing I did to the other person. What are you trying to do with this line ID code: **%1 %0 :: %file%**

Answer (score 0):

took me an hour but this should work

```
@echo off
set maxsize=3000
cd [path to the folder where the files are]
del size.txt
cls
for %%F in (*.txt) do (
    echo checking %%F
    FOR %%I in (%%F) do if %%~zI GEQ %maxsize% echo %%F>>size.txt
)
echo done!
pause > NUL
```