# If inside of if in batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42534912/cant-found-the-variable-with-number) which [Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo) gave.

But when I run the bat and get two `else` in…

```
If %%~zA Lss %MaxByteSize% (msg * algo) Else (
msg * O ficheiro exedeu 29Gb, diriga-se a Informatica))
```

…and have, for example another batch or a vb program, it will open it more than once, which is annoying.

Is there a way to make it possible not to open several times with something like:

```
If %%~zA Lss %MaxByteSize% (msg * algo) 
Else (
 If %something% lss 1 (msg * O ficheiro exedeu 29Gb, diriga-se a Informatica)
 Else ( )
%something%=%something%+1
)
```

*I'm not so good with code so that's why I'm "grabbing" code here and there.*

Comment: Run in a command prompt window `if /?` and read output help and see for example answers on [batch scripting - if exist ./sdcard/file.any using adb](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34118487/3074564) and on [IF ELSE syntax error within batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25471786/3074564)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for something like this:

```bat
@Echo Off
Rem If "%~1"=="" Exit/B

Set "MaxByteSize=31138512896"

Set "i=0"
For %%A In ("%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Outlook\*.ost") Do (
    Rem "%~1" "%~f0" :: "%%~fA"
    If %%~zA Gtr %MaxByteSize% Set/A "i+=1")
msg * %i% ficheiro exedeu 29Gb, diriga-se a Informatica
```

If you really are running the script with a single argument then remove both instances of **`Rem`**.